# How can I write circle coordinates to a shapefile using Python?

Tags: python, polygon, shapefile

I am very new to python so struggling! I have lat long coordinates for circles that I need to turn into a polygon shapefile from the current format (example shown of one circle):

```
[(39.1852751477193, -4.661967433717266), (39.185270807935424, -4.6620560715526205),
 (39.18525783015025, -4.6621438557678925), (39.18523633934382, -4.662229940952642),
 (39.18520654248149, -4.66231349805872), (39.185168726520814, -4.662393722384509),
 (39.1851232556481, -4.662469841324661), (39.185070567771184, -4.662541121810758),
 (39.18501117030217, -4.6626068773712275), (39.184945635270836, -4.662666474742481),
 (39.184874593815685, -4.662719339967662), (39.1847987301057, -4.662764963924225),
 (39.18471877475142, -4.662802907227118), (39.18463549776867, -4.662832804460353),
 (39.18454970116283, -4.662854367696218), (39.184462211205, -4.662867389268209),
 (39.1843738704744, -4.662871743771006), (39.1842855297438, -4.662867389268209),
 (39.184198039785976, -4.662854367696218), (39.18411224318014, -4.662832804460353),
 (39.18402896619739, -4.662802907227118), (39.18394901084311, -4.662764963924225),
 (39.18387314713312, -4.662719339967661), (39.18380210567796, -4.662666474742481),
 (39.18373657064664, -4.6626068773712275), (39.18367717317762, -4.662541121810758),
 (39.183624485300705, -4.662469841324661), (39.18357901442799, -4.662393722384509),
 (39.18354119846732, -4.662313498058719), (39.18351140160499, -4.662229940952642),
 (39.183489910798556, -4.6621438557678925), (39.18347693301339, -4.6620560715526205),
 (39.1834725932295, -4.661967433717266), (39.18347693323819, -4.661878795892798),
 (39.183489911239526, -4.661791011709759), (39.183511402245166, -4.661704926577361),
 (39.18354119928211, -4.661621369541729), (39.18357901538609, -4.66154114530178),
 (39.18362448636528, -4.661465026459563), (39.18367717430777, -4.661393746079731),
 (39.183736571798924, -4.661327990629777), (39.183802106808116, -4.6612683933690375),
 (39.1838731481977, -4.661215528250123), (39.183949011801204, -4.661169904391494),
 (39.18402896701218, -4.661131961174444), (39.184112243820316, -4.661102064011655),
 (39.18419804022694, -4.661080500828139), (39.184285529968605, -4.661067479288384),
 (39.1843738704744, -4.6610631247964704), (39.1844622109802, -4.661067479288384),
 (39.18454970072187, -4.66108050082814), (39.18463549712849, -4.661102064011656),
 (39.18471877393662, -4.661131961174444), (39.1847987291476, -4.661169904391494),
 (39.18487459275111, -4.661215528250122), (39.18494563414069, -4.6612683933690375),
 (39.18501116914988, -4.661327990629778), (39.18507056664104, -4.661393746079731),
 (39.18512325458352, -4.661465026459563), (39.18516872556272, -4.66154114530178),
 (39.185206541666695, -4.661621369541729), (39.18523633870364, -4.66170492657736),
 (39.18525782970928, -4.661791011709759), (39.185270807710616, -4.661878795892798),
 (39.1852751477193, -4.661967433717266)]
```

I have tried the code suggested by pyshp documentation but I cannot even get the test version to run:

```
import shapefile
w = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POLYGON)
w.poly(parts=[[[1,5],[5,5],[5,1],[3,3],[1,1]]])
w.field('FIRST_FLD','C','40')
w.field('SECOND_FLD','C','40')
w.record('First','Polygon')
w.save('shapefiles/test/polygon')
```

I then tried the solution suggested on a similar problem: [I cannot manage to export coordinates to a shapefile using Python. Is there a problem in my code or might the problem lie in the module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65288510/i-cannot-manage-to-export-coordinates-to-a-shapefile-using-python-is-there-a-pr)

which was:

shapefile.Writer() expects the filename as first parameter, so what you mean is probably:

```
w = shapefile.Writer('shapefiles/test/polygon')
```

and your last line should be instead

```
w.close()
```

but I get the error 'TypeError: poly() got an unexpected keyword argument 'parts'' - this is just when running the test polygon not using my own data.

I am not sure where I'm going wrong and how I would adapt the code to work for my circles?

Comment: Where does that `parts=` come from?

Comment: It's part of the example code for the test polygon on the pyshp documents. when you run it without 'parts=' the following error comes up: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: That seems to be a very old example code. Is just checked, by making the two modifications you have mentioned above and simply removing `parts=`, so that the code looks like the samples in the [documentation](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp#adding-geometry) it is working without any problem

Answer (score 0):

The code you have shown above should acutally be:

```py
import shapefile
w = shapefile.Writer('shapefiles/test/polygon')
w.poly([[[1,5],[5,5],[5,1],[3,3],[1,1]]])
w.field('FIRST_FLD','C','40')
w.field('SECOND_FLD','C','40')
w.record('First','Polygon')
w.close()
```

it seems that the version of `pyshp` and the documentation you have used do not match.

Comment: thank you! i have gotten it working now with both the test and circle coords